# Lettervalue plot with seaborn, using a pre-calculated KDE or histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to make a [letter value plot using seaborn](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lvplot.html) from a dataset that is too large to load into memory. Normally, I would do this:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_pickle('results_filename')
sns.lvplot(data=df, x='independent_variable', y='dependent_variable', hue='categorical_variable')
plt.show()  # or savefig(...)
```

But my PC starts thrashing when `results_filename` is more than a few `GB` in size.

I can calculate the KDEs or histograms and save those to disk instead of the observations themselves.
I do that often when plotting stuff with pure matplotlib.
But is it possible to use `sns.lvplot` (or something similar) without passing the observations themselves to it?

Comment: The `lvplot` is essentially a PatchCollection of Rectangles. So if you have the data from a histogram available you can just create the PatchCollection yourself.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Re-inventing seaborn is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: `lvplot` takes all data as input. If you want to avoid that, you cannot use it. An alternative is given in my comment above. How else can I help?